# Oracle Data Integrator logging history

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-data-integrator

I am currently working in ODI (Oracle Data Integrator 11g). In the Operator where all of the Track Logs are kept in the Date area is there a way that you can set how much of the history logs are saved. Right now it saves up to 8 months of logs but I only want to keep 1 month. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no setting for this. But you may create a package/interface to clean(or archive) older logs from repository.

I saw this method is used by more than one of my customers.